# React JS this.setState does nothing when updating content via a nested component

Tags: html, reactjs

I am working on a simple react example that will alter the content of a header on the screen based on what a user enters in a text field. Here's the react code:

```
var GreeterForm = React.createClass({
    onFormSubmit: function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var name = this.refs.name;

        this.refs.name.value = '';
        this.props.onNewName(name);
    },

    render: function(){
        return(
            <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
                <input type="text" ref="name"/>
                <button>Set Name</button>
            </form>
        );
    }
});

var Greeter = React.createClass({

    //returns an object of the default properties to be used
    //these are used if no properties are passed in
    getDefaultProps: function(){
        return {
            name: 'React!',
            message: "this is from a component!"
        };
    },

    //maintains a state for the component. Maintains the state as an object
    //this is a default method for react and we override it.
    getInitialState: function(){
       return {
            name: this.props.name
       };
    },

    handleNewName: function(name){
        this.setState({
            name: name
        });
    },

    //renders the greeter react component
    render: function() {
        var name = this.state.name;
        var message = this.props.message;
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Hello {name}!</h1>
                <p>{message}</p>

                <GreeterForm onNewName={this.handleNewName}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var firstName = "DefaultName";
var mess = "This is a message from react."

//note that name and message are passed in as properties
ReactDOM.render(<Greeter name={firstName} message={mess}/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

You can see that `GreeterForm` is nested within `Greeter` and is supposed to alter the content of the `h1` tag when the user submits.

However, the content of the `h1` tag is not changing. I sprinkled `alert(name.value)` along the code to ensure the correct name from the input field was being passed around, and that all checked out.

What could it be? Is something wrong with my `setState` function?

Here's the HTML if needed:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.1/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.1/react-dom.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">

    </div>
    <script type="text/babel" src="app.jsx"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: 1st check whether `handleNewName` is being called when you submit the form

Comment: @KishoreBarik I did that before submitting this question, I put an `alert` before `this.setState` in the `handleNewName` function and it appeared on the screen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not sending value of input. you are sending whole html element

in `onFormSubmit` function change this line

```
var name = this.refs.name;
```

to

```
var name = this.refs.name.value;
```